# Xrandr failed to get size of gamma for output default

Tags: display-resolution, radeon, xrandr

I'm trying to update the resolution of my monitor to 2560x1440. I have a Radeon graphics card and an MSI x570 motherboard.

I run the commands as follows:

```
mknox10@mknox10-MS-7C84:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1366 x 768, maximum 1366 x 768
default connected primary 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1366x768      76.00*
mknox10@mknox10-MS-7C84:~$ cvt 2560 1440 60
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 144
8 1493 -hsync +vsync
mknox10@mknox10-MS-7C84:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00"  31
2.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
mknox10@mknox10-MS-7C84:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode default "2560x1440_60.00"
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

After running the above commands the resolution does appear in the resolution dropdown in the display settings. But when I select it, it just defaults back to 1360x768. I have tried other resolutions like 1920x1080, and I know my monitor supports this resolution as it does so just fine when I'm running windows.

I'm not sure if they are related issues but my xrandr output gives an error saying:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
```

I have tried changing the GRUB_GFXMODE in my grub file. As well as trying to ubdate my drivers using `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. But nothing has worked so far.

Does anyone have a solution for this?